# Node Wrangler Error (Blender 4.0)

Tags: error

does anyone know what's happening with Node Wrangler in Blender 4.0 Alpha? Is it supposed to work, or is everyone encountering this error? Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE. Questions about not officially released blender versions are off-topic. The latest official released version is 3.6 LTS.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off topic because it is about troubleshooting temporary issues with unfinished, under development or experimental versions of software, which are expected to be working properly upon stable release. These transitory questions are unlikely to be useful in the future, rendering their long term value low, and making them unappealing for a knowledge database site.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: I confirm that from Sept 23 2023, this bug is now fixed.**

Although 4.0 is not officially released as said by Harry, this is a known bug for node Wrangler that is being fixed.

Next release should have a solution :
https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender-addons/issues/104865